# How to reset TotroiseSvn infos?

Tags: tortoisesvn, reset

I use TortoiseSVN at work, I started recently this job. Before I,
       other developer's Tortoise username and password's have recorded on
       pc. I have to remove other developer's infos but I could'nt. Although
       I tried remove tortoisesvn program and I downloaded again but I
       didn't do it, infos have recorded on pc still.

```
   additionally, I tried to clean authorized datas on setting but this
   button is disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Right click in any folder, go to “TortoiseSVN” on the context menu;
2. Select “Settings”; In the settings box, locate the item called
3. “Saved Data”; Click the “Clear” button that sits next to
4. “Authentication Data”;

from here https://placona.co.uk/changing-authentication-settings-tortoisesvn/

Comment: I tried this method but authentication data button is disabled,. Therefore, I tried other clear buttons but I didn't solve problem

Comment: you can try to delete folder C:\Users\<your-username>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth

Comment: yes, i tried to delete this file. After  I delete, I checked it but it failed

Answer (score 0):

The other instructions were not clear to me. When it said this I thought it meant inside the TortoiseSVN not inside file explorer. Also adding screenshots so it is clear.

`Right click in any folder, go to “TortoiseSVN” on the context menu;`

The settings for TortoiseSVN are difficult to find now if you do not know where to look. There is no file menu in TortoiseSVN. There is no right click options setting option inside TortoiseSVN.

Open file explorer. Go to this folder. There is a settings option there.

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\TortoiseSVN

https://pixhost.to/show/407/453348445_tortoisesvn_start_menu_folder.jpg

[url=https://pixhost.to/show/407/453348445_tortoisesvn_start_menu_folder.jpg][img]https://t94.pixhost.to/thumbs/407/453348445_tortoisesvn_start_menu_folder.jpg[/img][/url]

Open file explorer. Right click a file in explorer. You will see a TortoiseSVN menu. Then click settings.

https://pixhost.to/show/408/453349448_tortoisesvn_file_menu.jpg

[url=https://pixhost.to/show/408/453349448_tortoisesvn_file_menu.jpg][img]https://t94.pixhost.to/thumbs/408/453349448_tortoisesvn_file_menu.jpg[/img][/url]

https://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=Configuring_SVN_on_Windows

Then you can follow the instructions that were mentioned in the other post.

Try the following:

1. Right click in any folder, go to “TortoiseSVN” on the context menu;
2. Select “Settings”; In the settings box, locate the item called
3. “Saved Data”; Click the “Clear” button that sits next to
4. “Authentication Data”;

from here https://placona.co.uk/changing-authentication-settings-tortoisesvn/